# Enable HTTP 2.0 for Undertow in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wonder how I can enable the HTTP 2.0 for Undertow using Spring Boot, I monitored the protocol and currently HTTPS is using 1.1.

Is there any property for it? Or should I create a EmbeddedServletContainerFactory with this option.

Tks,

Comment: I found out that Spring Boot 1.3, using Undertow 1.3.5 with Java 8 only needs to set up on java execution -Xbootclasspath/p:C:\alpn-boot-8.1.6.v20151105.jar to work HTTP 2.0. As you may now HTTP 2.0 just works for https protocol...

Comment: Can you clarify what SpringBoot version do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following bean to the configuration

```
    @Bean
    UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(
                builder -> builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true));
        return factory;
    }
```

Then start the application with alpn-boot-8.1.9.v20160720.jar in the boot class path

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:<<location>>/alpn-boot-8.1.9.v20160720.jar -jar <<your application>>
```