# Spring Boot: How to configure HTTP/2 for Embedded Jetty (or Undertow)?

Tags: spring-boot

AFAIK Tomcat doesn't support HTTP/2 so far. Therefore, I want to use Jetty (or Undertow as another alternative), but don't know how configure the Embedded Jetty so that the ALPN JAR file can be used. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: See this article for switching to Undertow and using ALPN. This covers both server and client. https://vanwilgenburg.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/spring-boot-http2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable HTTP 2.0 for Undertow in Spring Boot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834331/enable-http-2-0-for-undertow-in-spring-boot)